# Ideas for a 5 to 7 day hike in Japan

Tags: japan, camping, hiking, trekking, hokkaido

In august I will be going to japan. After visiting a friend, I want to go on a trekking for 5 to 7 days.

Ideally I would go to Hokkaido for that, because then I can leave my stuff that I do not need for the trekking at my friends house. I would also escape the warmer climate of the main island that way.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips of where to go for a nice trekking. I prefer to go somewhere where it is not too crowded.

In the lonely planet "hiking in japan" book, the "Daisetsuzan grand traverse" is described. I've found a lot of information about it on http://www.idioimagers.org/Daisetsuzan-guide.htm already, and also plotted the route out on a map (used the UUD maps that can be used with Garmin devices)

For who's interested:

GPX file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3M3QULFICJwdmdZR3JoRlotTEk/edit?usp=sharing
or view on google map: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://gpx2kml.com/public/2014/03/16/skcmfexpj_Daisetsuzan.kml

As you can see when you view it on Google maps or in google earth, it's quite a tough route. It almost goes all the way over the highest ridges, so I guess it can become quite a ordeal when the weather turns bad. I think I will be able to do this hike (I've done trekking where I've gone 25KM with 1000m altitude difference and 20KG on my back before), but I'm not sure I would enjoy it if it's this hard.

Are there any less demanding hikes around, I would even prefer not going to higher altitudes, but have a bit more forests on my route. I will bring all gear to be self supporting (tent, cooking gear, sleeping gear, etc..), since I prefer to avoid huts.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't been myself, but have always heard that the Shiretoko Peninsula at the northeastern edge of Hokkaido is the crowning jewel of natural Hokkaido.  The mountains there are not as high, and you'll be out close to the sea facing Russia.

This guy lives in Hokkaido and has done a [a big hike around Shiretoko](http://www.hokkaidonokuma.com/shiretokorando.htm).

Also, though it would not take your entire 5-7 days, I can confirm that [Rebun Island makes for an amazing hike in August](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e6877.html).  It is an island located off the coast of Wakkanai, the northern-most edge of Hokkaido (and Japan).

Answer (score 2):

My friend recently did a 7 - 8 day hike from Tateyama to Kamikochi. It's quite intense, but you can either choose huts or just camp at sites or wherever else. You could easily cut parts out to fit your schedule.

This isn't my friend's blog, but it is the [same trek with more info](http://maikuinjapan.blogspot.jp/2010/08/tateyama-to-kamikochi-day-one.html)

If you're looking for more specific information, update the question and I'll relay answers back.